# Open different Web page with button on single ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, webview

I know how to implement webview in my app and now I want to use only one ViewController to open different webpages of my site, like this:

First viewcontroller has buttons: button1, button2 and button3.

Then in second viewcontroller:

- if button1 clicked: `mysite.com`
- if button2 clicked: `mysite.com/page`
- if button3 clicked: `mySite.com/Page2`

So far I have created one viewcontroler per category, so I have many categories and it is more frustrating.

I want sumthing like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you add some code and screen shots?

Answer (score 1):

[image]Yes you can open multiple links in same web view by clicking on different buttons like

```
 myWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,   self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-100))

        myWebView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)

    let Button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10,self.view.frame.size.height-50,50,50))
         Button1.setTitle("Link 1", forState: .Normal)

        Button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
        Button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button1Action), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

         self.view.addSubview(Button1)


        let Button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(150,self.view.frame.size.height-50,50,50))
         Button2.setTitle("Link 1", forState: .Normal)
        Button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)

        Button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button2Action), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(Button2)

         let Button3 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(250,self.view.frame.size.height-50,50,50))
         Button3.setTitle("Link 1", forState: .Normal)
        Button3.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)

        Button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button3Action), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(Button3)
     }

     func button1Action()
    {
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.co.in")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
       myWebView.loadRequest(request)

    }

     func button2Action()
    {

         let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        myWebView.loadRequest(request)

    }

    func button3Action()
    {
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916960/open-diffrent-webpage-with-button-on-single-viewcontroller")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        myWebView.loadRequest(request)

    }
```

And don't forget to set in info.plist App Transport Security Settings to Allow arbitrary load true[image]

Comment: how can i name my button ? in segue ?

Comment: I am using swift ..  "CGRectMake" Is Unavailble in Swift